# LiveData not updating after database change on Worker

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

I have a Worker that send some images to a server. When the Worker starts, I need to change my view status to "In progress" and when the Worker finish, I need to change my view status to "Finished". But, when I update the **Room Database** inside the Worker, my view can't understand that the database has changed and the **LiveData** is not notified.
If I make the same call before the Worker starts, the **LiveData** understand the changes and updates my View. The problem that I have is that my view doesn't know exactly what item of the **recyclerview** it should update, so I can't observe the Worker on the View. I need to make this update inside the Worker.

**--- Updated with code ---**

**Fragment**

```
viewModel.shortHistoryViewModelList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { 
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        adapter.replace(shortHistories)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
        scrollToItem(shortHistories)
})
```

**ViewModel**

```
private val results: MediatorLiveData<List<ShortHistory>> = MediatorLiveData()
init {
    this.state.value = NetworkStateEnum.NONE
    results.addSource(repository.get()) {
        results.postValue(it)
    }
}

val shortHistoryViewModelList: LiveData<List<ShortHistoryViewModel>> =
        Transformations.switchMap(results) { shortHistories ->
            val mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<ShortHistoryViewModel>> = MutableLiveData()
            val list = ArrayList<ShortHistoryViewModel>()

            for (shortHistory in shortHistories) {
                list.add(ShortHistoryViewModel(shortHistory))
            }
            mutableLiveData.value = list
            mutableLiveData
        }
```

**Worker**

```
val shortHistory = shortHistoryRepository.get(shipmentId)
shortHistory.digitalReceipt = shortHistory.digitalReceipt?.copy(status = DigitalReceiptStatusEnum.Sending.value)
shortHistoryRepository.insert(shortHistory)
```

Comment: Add your code, we can't help you without knowing what your code does.

Comment: I don't think that my code will change anything in this situation. When I use the same code in a different point, it works.

Comment: Do add relevant code.

Comment: Updated with code

Answer (score 0):

UI can only be updated from the UI Thread ( which is also the main Thread ) and not in any other thread like the `Worker` you are using. Use `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)` method inside your Worker thread to run any code that has to do with updating the UI.

Comment: But if I use runOnUiThread to update my Database it will crash, right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what problem you are having since you are refusing to post relevant code but I suspect that you are changing the livedata inside a worker thread. If that is the case, you need to notify the livedata that it has changed by calling its postValue() method.

Comment: I'm not refusing to post my code, but my code is kinda Complex to post in here. I have a UI that Observe the LiveData that get the results from Room DataBase. And I have a Worker that updates the DataBase. I can't postValue there, because Room is supposed to do that.

Comment: He's updating the database, he should not have to call postValue()

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem.

I found that If we run room-db @RawQuery, then liveData or kotlin flow don't get updated.

So, we have to use normal @Update query instead of @RawQuery.